# javax.sound.sampled.clip Terminating before playing sound

Tags: java, audio, javax.sound.sampled

I am so confused as to why this is terminating straight away... The debugger so far has been no real help.. I am sure the code is running the whole way through.

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;

/**
 * An example of loading and playing a sound using a Clip. This complete class
 * isn't in the book ;)
 */
public class ClipTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // specify the sound to play
    // (assuming the sound can be played by the audio system)
    File soundFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Benny\\Desktop\\AudioSample\\Austin.wav");
    AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);

    // load the sound into memory (a Clip)
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, sound.getFormat());
    Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    clip.open(sound);
    // due to bug in Java Sound, explicitly exit the VM when
    // the sound has stopped.
    clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
      public void update(LineEvent event) {
        if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
          event.getLine().close();
          System.exit(0);
        }
      }
    });
    // play the sound clip
    clip.start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `clip.start()` causes the sound to be played on a different thread, namely on the "Java Sound Event Dispatcher" thread. The main thread proceeds normally, and the application is exited.

Depending on *how* and *when* exactly you want to play this clip, there are different solutions. Quite often, there are no additional precautions necessary. For example, in a game, you want to play in-game sounds, but when the game exits, then no more sounds should be played. And usually, you will *not* exit the application with `System.exit(0)` at all - and especially not after an arbitrary clip has finished playing...

However, in this example, you might use a `CountDownLatch`.

```
final CountDownLatch clipDone = new CountDownLatch(1);
clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
    @Override
    public void update(LineEvent event) {
        if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
            event.getLine().close();
            clipDone.countDown();
        }
    }
});
// play the sound clip and wait until it is done
clip.start();
clipDone.await();
```

Comment: Do you know anywhere to get my hands on some decent documentation for the javax.sound.* Package as the "Official Tutorial" I find rather long winded and confusing.

Comment: I noticed It would run fine If I opened a Jframe at the same time.

Comment: When you open a JFrame, then the application will stay alive until the Frame is closed. Unfortunately, I don't know a "better" documentation (but I agree that, for example, compared to the "Swing HowTo" sites, the documentation is difficult to understand ... fortunately, a websearch usually brings some stackoverflow answers, at least ;-))